# Missing Resource Type: received resource data with a type 'events' but no schema could be found with that name

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api

I have a basic Rails 7 application that uses the `jsonapi-resources` gem. On the Rails side of the application, I implemented a simple structure of two resources - `events` and `event_categories`. They are connected to each other through associations:

```rb
has_one :category, class_name: "EventCategory", exclude_links: %i[self related]
```

```rb
has_many :events
```

Everything works successfully through Postman. `include`, `fields[*]` and sorting work.

**Well, that is, everything is fine with the Rails part.**

**The problem is only with Ember.**

From their documentation, I conclude that Ember out of the box can work with JSON:API using the `JSONAPIAdapter`. But I immediately get this error:

> Error while processing route: events.index Assertion Failed: Missing Resource Type: received resource data with a type 'events' but no schema could be found with that name. Error: Assertion Failed: Missing Resource Type: received resource data with a type 'events' but no schema could be found with that name.

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Assertion Failed: Missing Resource Type: received resource data with a type 'events' but no schema could be found with that name.

```js
// app/models/event.js

import Model, { attr } from '@ember-data/model';

export default class EventModel extends Model {
  @attr('string') note;
  @attr('string') scheduled_on;
}
```

Tell me, please, what is the problem?